# MariaDB UPDATE ROW_COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, rowcount

I have the following table (tnTEST) :-

| fnidx | fntext | fnrownum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | aa | null |
| 11 | bb | null |
| 12 | cc | null |
| 13 | dd | null |
| 14 | ee | null |

and would like to use UPDATE and ROW_COUNT to produce this :-

| fnidx | fntext | fnrownum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | aa | 1 |
| 11 | bb | 2 |
| 12 | cc | 3 |
| 13 | dd | 4 |
| 14 | ee | 5 |

How do I do this? I'm using MariaDB.

The following is not working:

```
UPDATE tnTEST 
SET fnrownum = rcn
FROM (SELECT fnidx AS rci, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY fnidx) AS rcn
      FROM tnTEST)
WHERE rci == fnidx;
```